# R for loop not printing out the desired result with Grubbs' test

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R, and I was trying to run a Grubbs' Test through each column of the dataframe "heptathlon" in R Markdown. So, I used a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(heptathlon)) {
  grubbs.test(heptathlon[ ,i], type = 10, opposite = FALSE, two.sided = FALSE)
}
```

But it prints nothing after running the code. I also tried a while loop:

```
i <- 1
while (i <= ncol(heptathlon)) {
  grubbs.test(heptathlon[ ,i], type = 10, opposite = FALSE, two.sided = FALSE)
  i = i+1
}
```

Same result, it prints nothing. I'm not sure what could be missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: By default nothing will print inside a loop. If you want the value to print, use `print(grubbs.test(heptathlon[ ,i], type = 10, opposite = FALSE, two.sided = FALSE))`

Comment: Ah, got it. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
Haven't checked arguments of `grubbs.test()`.

EDIT: Found relevant packages and dataset:

```
library(HSAUR) 
library(outliers)
heptathlon <- heptathlon

grubbsT <- c()
# does not make much sense to test "score", therefore (ncol(..)-1)
for (i in 1:(ncol(heptathlon)-1)) {
  
  # store resulst in the vector 
  grubbsT[i] <- round(grubbs.test(heptathlon[ ,i], 
                                  type = 10)$p.value, digits=5) 
  # assuming the test works if you input an arbitrary column of your 
  # df, and also, you want to get the p-values   
  
}
```

Output:

```
# inspect vector of p.values
grubbsT
#> [1] 0.000 0.000 0.370 0.305 0.046 1.000 0.002
```

Created on 2021-09-14 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

Comment: For some reason it yielded an error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" repeated several times, then ran the test anyway. So I guess it worked somewhat! It didn't print out the p-value for each column, however, only the test statistic G and U.

Comment: Saw the edit. This works, thank you!

Comment: I edited it again.